# How to determine number of allowable wires in a crimp wire connector?

Tags: connector, datasheet, wire, gauge

I bought a pack of single-ended crimp-style [connectors](http://www.te.com/usa-en/product-53915-1.html#guest-click) at a standard hardware store. The [data sheet](http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Specification%20Or%20Standard%7F408-1003%7FL%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_SS_408-1003_L.pdf%7F53915-1) specifies allowable wire configurations, but I am having trouble reading it.

The linked data sheet contains a table *(see bottom of post for text description)*:
[image]

However, all the cell values have a dash in them.  For example, the package says `Max 5 22 gauge wires`, but I don't see a clear way to derive this from the table.  These values exist:

- row = 22 wire size, number of wires = 1, column = size 22, value = `4-14`
- row = 22 wire size, number of wires = 4, column = size 22, value = `1-11`

**What does the first and last numbers mean?** Does the type of wire (stranded/solid) factor into the table?

> Description of the table, in case the image above (or linked
>   datasheet) is inaccessible:
>
> - On the left is `wire size`
>
>   - there are row headers such as `size 22`
>   - each row header has sub headers such as `1`, `2`, `3`, etc.
> - On the top , there is "number of additional wires of one wire type"
>
>   - there are column headers such as `size 22`

Comment: remember that if the wires are too small the wire nut can slip off..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the table it looks like the MINIMUM number of 22 AWG wires is 5 with a maximum of 15.

I think the '-' is to be interpreted as 'to'.  So '4-14' means 4 wires up to 14 wires. (Notice that in the case of 22AWG all the combinations add up to values between 5 (minimum) and 15 which is the maximum allowed for 22AWG).

In the case of wires larger than 12 AWG you can only add one extra wire so there is no hyphen.

Comment: The datasheet confirms that 5 wires 22 awg are the minimum loading. Your information seems correct.

Comment: This does seem right.  Odd that the package says, verbatim: "**Maximum wire configuration:** 5 #22 AWG wires."